# Why is a string's byte size longer than the length?

Tags: c, string, byte, sizeof

Why is it that `sizeof("Bill")` is `5` but `sizeof(char)` is `1`?

Shouldn't that make `sizeof("Bill")` be `4` since the length of the string is 4 chars (`4 x 1`)?

I believe it may have something to do with `"Bill"` being an array of characters, but why does that increase the byte size?

Comment: @H2CO3 - I concur - this is simple C programming that is usually covered within the first couple of chapters of a reasonable programming book on C (or C++)

Comment: That's no reason not to use this question as a place to write a good canonical answer and hopefully improve the internet a little bit.

Comment: @EdHeal Maybe a vote for closure would be a good sign of you concurring ;) I totally agree, this question fits very well the "shows no research effort" term in the FAQ.

Comment: @H2CO3 - Give me a chance - I only have one pair of hands (and one keyboard!)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

C strings are null terminated.  There is a zero byte at the end of that string.  Assuming ASCII, `"Bill"` looks like this in memory:

```
'B'  'i'  'l'  'l'  '\0'
0x42 0x69 0x6c 0x6c 0x00
```

From the C standard, Section **6.4.5 String literals**, paragraph 7:

> In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.

If you want to get an answer of `4` for the length, you should use `strlen("Bill")`, rather than `sizeof`.

If you really don't want the null-terminator, that's possible too, though probably ill-advised.  This definition:

```
char bill[4] = "Bill";
```

will yield a 4-byte array `bill` containing just the characters `'B'`, `'i'`, `'l'`, and `'l'`, with no null-terminator.

Answer (score 3):

it has a 0 as a terminator character,  so its  `B i l l 0`